# Prestashop Rewrite Rule Renders Wrong Image Path

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

We are currently using prestashop 1.5.6.2 and imported a huge xml file (14k row) into mysql via 3rd party php functions. 
Everything fine till product page in prestashop.
But in product page prestashop calling image like

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/img/p/1/1/3/113-large_default.jpg" title="Product Name" alt="Product Name" id="bigpic" width="264" height="264">
```

We expect

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/img/p/113/113-large_default.jpg" title="Product Name" alt="Product Name" id="bigpic" width="264" height="264">
```

Unfortuanetly; Prestashop adding slashes between first product id like;

```
/1/1/3/113-large_default.jpg
```

I'm not sure but it's some kind of .htaccess rewriterule problem. 
Our .htaccess looks like;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

# Disable Multiviews
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com.tr$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com.tr$
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com.trm$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com.trm$
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404
```

Does anyone can help if they have had some kind of issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rewrite problem, the image path is correct.

If you want to use your custom image path then in `product.tpl` change the image tag with the following:

```
<img src="img/p/{$product->id}/{$product->id}-large_default.jpg">
```

Comment: thanks for reply. In my product.tpl default `<img src="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $cover.id_image, 'large_default')}" />` , adding slashes and result `<img src="img/p/1/1/3/113-large_default.jpg"> i want result `<img src="img/p/113/113-large_default.jpg">` how should i change tpl image src i tried in product-list.tpl `<img src="img/p/{$product.id_product}/{$product.id_product}-large_default.jpg">` it's working. But in product.tpl it's going a white screen.

Comment: @HddnTHA In `product.tpl` try `<img src="img/p/{$product->id}/{$product->id}-large_default.jpg">`

Comment: @yenshiark thank you very much. Can you edit your answer as this comment above? I'll accept it as correct answer!

Comment: can you please take a look at this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270704/prestashop-1-5-6-2-shows-wrong-products-in-the-category-frontoffice

Answer (score 0):

Copied from Jon Lin's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899254/wrong-path-issues-on-rewriting-urls-with-querystrings/29899399)

> The extra slash in the URL changes the relative URL base. All your
>   links that are relative URLs in your content will now use the
>   incorrect base. You can fix this by either using absolute URL's
>   (starts with a `/`) or add a base in your page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```