# Wrong Path Issues On Rewriting URLs With Querystrings

Tags: .htaccess

What I want is this link

```
gallery/1
```

to be headed to

```
gallery.php?id=1
```

and what I wrote for that in my `.htaccess` file is

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*)? gallery.php?id=$1
```

which lets me get that id as i want but nothing on the page shows up because it assumes now all file paths starts with `gallery`. Like when a path for an image should be `img/icon.png`, it is now `gallery/img/icon.png` so it won't show up. How to fix this? I guess I so misunderstood something about url rewriting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra slash in the URL changes the relative URL base. All your links that are relative URLs in your content will now use the incorrect base. You can fix this by either using absolute URL's (starts with a `/`) or add a base in your page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: Solves the problem. So you're saying this has nothing to do with .htaccess rules?

Comment: @BatuZet Jon's answer is correct. you can also use `/` in front of your links but that would require you updating them all. Base tag is a faster easier fix.

Comment: @BatuZet The rules themselves aren't breaking your links, but the rules do make it so the browser goes to a URL with an extra `/` in the path, and the browser (knowing nothing about the internal rewriting your rules do) simply thinks the `/gallery/` is the base to prepend all relative URLs you have in your content. If you used absolute URL's, this wouldn't have happened.

Comment: I would have never figured out this solution by myself, thank you Jon!!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is your image sources and not your.httaccess. If your images use

```
src="img/icon.png"
```

and you are in yourwebsite.com/gallery, then your images will become `yourwebsite.com/gallery/img/icon.png`.

Try changing the sources to either include the full URL `(yourwebsite.com/img/icon.png)` or the path from root `(/img/icon.png)`.

Answer (score 2):

In `mod_rewrite`, you can indicate that certain rewrite rules apply *only* if one or several conditions are met.

In this situation, you want the rule only to apply if the URI begins with `gallery`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^gallery
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.+) gallery.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Your condition will never match which will cause the rewrite rule to not be executed because REQUEST_URI requires a leading slash in the URI. Also it's redundant because the rewrite rule already is matching against that.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `RewriteCond` before the `RewriteRule`. Try this:

```
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" ^gallery
RewriteRule ^gallery/([0-9]+) /gallery.php?id=$1
```

Your `(.*)?` expression is incorrect because `*` will match zero or more characters (you want one or more numbers, from your example), and `?` is redundant used with `*`.

Comment: Your rule will never work correctly in htaccess. Also that's incorrect use of REQUEST_FILENAME. Although I agree he should not use the greedy `*` Not sure why this was upvoted twice.