# Prestashop 1.5.6.2 shows wrong products in the category (FrontOffice)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I'm using prestashop 1.5.6 and make a bulk category and product operation into mysql via 3rd party libraries (which i was wrote). Everything fine till some of my products show in wrong category.
For eg i have A product in A category;
But when i go to the B category A product is also there.
I think something wrong with my `ps_category_product` table with position column.
I'm updating this table with code below;

```
$sqlFirst = 'SELECT id_product, id_category_default, xml_id_product FROM ps_shop_product';
$queryFirst = $db->prepare($sqlFirst);
$queryFirst->execute();
while ($rowFirst = $queryFirst->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){ 
    $sqlProductAddCatPosFirst = '
        INSERT INTO ps_shop_category_product
        (id_product, id_category, position)
        VALUES 
        (?, ?, ?)
        ';
    // ps_shop_category_product Sql sorgumuzu hazırlayalım
    $queryProductAddCatPosFirst = $db->prepare($sqlProductAddCatPosFirst);
    $queryProductAddCatPosFirst->bindParam(1, $rowFirst->id_product, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $queryProductAddCatPosFirst->bindParam(2, $rowFirst->id_category_default, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $queryProductAddCatPosFirst->bindParam(3, $rowFirst->id_product, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    // ps_shop_category_product Hazır Sql sorgumuzu çalıştıralım
    $queryProductAddCatPosFirst->execute();
}
```

But everything fine on `Backoffice > Products > Filter By Category` tab.
It shows correct products under category. Is there any specific detail in Front Office? If i truncate table `(ps_category_product)`, my products dont shown in categories in Front Office. What am i missing?

**Any help will greatly appricated.**

**Update**

After @bcsteeve s comment, i create a sample category from BackOffice and all products shown in correct categories. When i look at the changes on my mysql tables; only `ps_category` table has changed some values  `nleft` and `nright` columns.

In my simple webservice, i assign `nleft` and `nright` to 0 (zero). But now they have some values different then 0 (zero).

Now i think my problem is recalculating hierarchy of `ps_category` table.

> Is there any specific prestashop core controller and/or method that
>   can recalculate nleft and nright values on `ps_category` table?
>   Because i dont want to add category manually after my webservice is
>   update my products and categories.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @yenshirak may be you can help (:

Comment: The `position` column in `ps_category_product` determines the position of the product in the category so I don't think that this would be the problem. Is this the only script that is inserting into  `ps_category_product`?

Comment: @yenshirak actually i have a big and complex script which is adding categories and products from some xml feeds.

Comment: @yenshirak do you know how can i query (in mysql) `products from specific category id` I want to look at category for duplicate products on `phpMyAdmin`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ps_category_product WHERE id_category = 1`

Comment: @yenshirak it's returning true products in the category. But i dont know why still showing wrong products on FrontOffice. /-:

Comment: Triple check that you've cleared all cache both in your server and browser.  That helped for me.  If it doesn't, then add a dummy category manually and move a product into it. Does that one show up correctly?

Comment: @bcsteeve when i add a category manually from backoffice my products shown in the correct category. It's about `ps_category` table's `nleft` and `nright` columns. I assigned them as 0 with my simple webservice. Now they have some values. I understand it's about category hierarchy. But which data's should i add for them? nleft means before this category nrgiht means after this category?

Comment: @yenshirak do you know how can i regenerate `nleft` and `nright` on `ps_category` table?

Comment: @yenshirak i found `require_once '../config/config.inc.php';
try {
 Category::regenerateEntireNtree();
}
catch (CategoryException $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
}` it worked. Btw thanks for help.

Comment: @yenshirak can you please answer this question? Because bounties are not refundable to owners and if i answer my own question it doenst effect my reputation. I don't want to waste 50 rep (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can regenerate the `nleft` and `nright` columns of the `ps_category` table with the following code:

```
require_once '../config/config.inc.php';

try {
  Category::regenerateEntireNtree();
} catch (CategoryException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in prestashop 1.6.
Switch off cache if you have file cache selected.
Cache switched on after few minutes and all back to work again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, products list in category page are wrong, i upgraded the layered navigation module and it had fixed the problem, i think i should create some indexing crons for this module